# Forward touch events from overlay UIView to UIScrollView below after using them

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, touch

I have a question concerning the touch handling in iOS / Swift:

My project looks like this

```
UIViewController
     → UIView
          → OverlayView (UIView)
          → ScrollView (UIScrollView)
```

The OverlayView lays on top of the UIScrollView. Both are subviews of the UIViewControllers view.

The reason why I'm doing this is, that I want the scroll view to behave normally (panning, zooming) while the overlay view is not affected by the changes in the visible content of the scroll view. Furthermore the overlay view should handle touch events to display guidelines for the content in the scroll view below.

The problem I'm facing right now is, that the touch events (`touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, `touchesEnded`, `touchesCancelled`) on the overlay view are not proceeded to the scroll view (scroll view does not pan/zoom).

I found a solution for forwarding touch events to the next view below by overriding the `point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool` and returning `false`. But then the touch events on the overlay view won't get called.

Has anyone an idea how to implement this behavior? I tried calling all the touch events on the next responder in the overlay view, but this didn't work either.

Thanks in advice for your help!

Comment: Intstead of using overview on scrollview, create subclass of UIScrollview and handle touches there.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think you were on the right track with `point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool`.

In your "overlay" view, check if the point is inside a subview. If so, return true to allow interaction with the subview. If not, return false to "pass the touch" through to the underlying scroll view.

```
class PassThruOverlayView: UIView {

    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {

        for v in subviews {

            let ptInSub = v.convert(point, from: v.superview)
            if v.bounds.contains(ptInSub) {
                return true
            }

        }

        return false

    }

}
```

You can see a working example here (showing both "Overlapping ScrollViews" and "UIView Overlay on ScrollView): https://github.com/DonMag/ScrollViewPassThru

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem is, that I need the touch event both in the overlay view and the scroll view :-/

Comment: hmmm... so, you want to - for example - tap a button in the overlay view and have that trigger an action ***and*** have that same tap trigger something in the underlying scrollview?

Comment: Exactly! The purpose of this is, that I have some kind of drawing canvas within the scroll view and want to insert guidelines for precise drawing at the overlay view. The reason why I'm doing this that way is, that I want the guidelines not to zoom with the content of the scroll view.

Comment: Can you maybe show an example of what you are trying to do? Do you have, for example, a `UISlider` on the overlay view, and as you drag the slider back-and-forth you *also* want a line being drawn on the "canvas"? I would think you want either the touch to register on a part of the overlay **or** have it register on the canvas, but not both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to look up `hitTest` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest)) - create logic in your subclass (overlay) that decides when you want to pass touch events down to the view below